# BigSur Click on Dock App does not change to Space with App

Tags: big-sur, spaces

On catalina and earlier osx, I used to click on the app on dock to switch between spaces. This seems not to be working on BigSur.

Strangely, I couldn't find anything about this on the internet... I would expect more people to be complaining about it. If this is an isolated behaviour, please let me know.

Otherwise, anyone has any hints on how to get back to the previous behaviour?

Comment: It stopped working properly in Mojave. Check you have system prefs > Mission Control > 'When switching to an application, switch to a Space with open windows for the application' **on**. [This will fail if you have any app spread to more than one Space… but that always would. Spaces cannot handle multiple Spaces for a single app, not in design spec.]

Comment: Many thanks, this was actually the point. Dunno if I should delete the question or whether you should answer it and keep it for further reference...

Comment: I can throw it in an an answer - it lets me have another rant about how Spaces development was abandoned when Fullscreen was introduced & hasn't seen any improvement since. One day, who knows, Apple might even notice & do something about it ;))

Comment: Then throw the answer and let's contribute to internet's collective knowledge :)

Comment: I left out the rant ;))

Comment: Perfect, let's hope one day apple notice it and fix that problem which gives me many headaches too, particularly for Finder....

Comment: Finder is the one that broke at Mojave. Clicking the Dock icon works, but clicking a bit of visible Desktop no longer does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behaviour is toggled on a pref…

System Preferences > Mission Control > 'When switching to an application, switch to a Space with open windows for the application'
This needs to be **on** for the behaviour you desire.

It will fail if you have any app spread to more than one Space… but that always would. Spaces cannot handle multiple Spaces for a single app, that's not within design spec.